# What is the proper and accurate way to measure space for window screens?

Tags: windows, installation, exterior, screens

One of our metal windows is missing a screen and I'd like to replace it.  I don't have other windows of the same size so I can't easily copy the screen dimensions.  How should I measure the window opening so that the new screen will install properly?  The instructions that were included with my screen framing kit are insufficient and literally say "measure the opening".

Mr. Google suggested measuring the full length of the screen opening and subtracting 1/16".  If I do that though, I would think that the screen would be too big to fit.  Can I get some advise on where exactly I should measure?

Comment: What do you mean by "metal window"?  Exactly what type of window is it?  Casement?  Double hung?  Single Hung?  Slider?

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo It's a single pane window with metal frame.

Comment: Do you mean a storm window mounted exterior to the main window?  Can you post a pic of this window?

Comment: Do you want to replace just the screen (do you have an existing frame for the screen you can use)?  Or do you need a new frame and screen?

Comment: @auujay Both frame and screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get to hung up on the exact size the piece of screen needs to be. simply measure the width and height of the frame and buy a piece of screen large enough. Normally it comes in standard widths and cut to length.  Once you lay and stretch the screen  over your frame, install the spline on one end, stretch, install sides and opposite end. An inexpensive spline roller comes in handy here. Use some sharp scissors, utility knife or shears and trim off the excess close to the spline. Done!

Answer (score 0):

You have other windows of the same design, if not the same size.

Find the track the screen goes into, and measure it in four places (across top, bottom, left, right).  Measure the matching screen (top, bottom, left, right) to be sure it's square.  Subtract B from A. Now measure your target window's track, and adjust appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Take a tape measure and measure the width by putting the tape measure in the deepest channel and measure across to the other end and take off 1/4 inch. Do the same for the height.